# SQL get the IDs of the records that are null and no other records has values for the same ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data:

```
ID    From             To
----------------------------------
1      NULL            NULL
1      NULL            NULL
1      2019-01-01      2019-01-01
2      NULL            NULL
2      NULL            NULL
3      NULL            NULL
3      2019-02-01      2019-02-01
```

I need to get the IDs of the records that have NULL values in all of its records, in From and To fields.

For example, based on the above data I should get ID 2.

Comment: based on your requirement I think you should get both ID 3 and 2 as an output

Comment: @PrajaktaKale, if I had to guess, when Hasan was building the sample data, they intended that last row to have an `id` value of 3, but copied and pasted from above and forgot to change the `id` value. No harm done, but your observation is correct.

Comment: Yes, it should be 3. Thank you. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using `NOT IN` operator.

```
create table TestTable (id int, FromDt Date, ToDt Date)
Insert into TestTable Values
    (1, NULL, NULL), 
    (1, NULL, NULL), 
    (1, '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01'),
    (2, NULL, NULL),
    (2, NULL, NULL),
    (3, NULL, NULL),
    (1, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01')

Select 
     distinct Id 
From TestTable where FromDt is null and ToDt is null
and id not in (Select t.Id from TestTable t 
         where t.fromDt is not null and t.toDt is not null)
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f35800023bdea650d423896e3cde01d) demo.

It looks like as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having max(from) is null and max(to) is null;
```

Note that `from` and `to` are SQL keywords, so they are very bad for column names.  I didn't escape the values, assuming that you just simplified the column names for your question.

Comment: very nice simple answer.Can you explain how it works?

Comment: @HasanShouman . . . It is calculating the maximum and minimum values for each id.  These are only `NULL` if all the values are `NULL` for a given `id`.

Comment: @HasanShouman . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: It is returning the ids that have entries with non-null values, if there is another record with the same id has null values

Comment: @HasanShouman . . . This *cannot* return `id` that have `NULL` values in either `from` or `to`.  If there are other columns you want to consider, they need to be part of the `having` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's method is far more concise, and I'd wager more efficient, though I haven't tested that. But just as an alternative, another way to find list elements that do, or do not, occur in conjunction with some other element is to use a `WHERE EXISTS` clause. Or, in the negative case like this one, a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause.

```
select distinct
    id
from 
    mytable as t1
where 
    not exists (select 1
                from mytable as t2
                where [to] is not null
                and t2.id = t1.id)
    and
    not exists (select 1
                from mytable as t2
                where [from] is not null
                and t2.id = t1.id);
```

Comment: I was going to comment on @Gordon Linoff, not exists performs best where return values are not needed.  For brevity could you write Where not exists (select 1 from mytable as t2 where ([to] is not null or [from] is not null) and t2.id = t1.id) ?

Comment: @JJ32, I closed my fiddle already, but that ought to work. If brevity is the goal, though, I still think Gordon wins. Using the two WHERE clauses, in my opinion, makes the code a little more self-explanatory. If I weren't in the middle of something else, I might take the time to see if your version and mine generate different query plans.... Maybe I'll circle back tonight. :)

Comment: Makes total sense.  I was hoping the Not Exists option would be showcased, as my experience is that works better for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Please [refer](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02b404825c3878dac9534b292833d208) this for solution. And you should not use reserved keywords like From and to as a column names.

```
select id from sample  group by id having max(From_) is null and max(To_) is null;
```

I replaced from and to by from_ and To_ .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    D.Id 
FROM 
    dbo.YourDataTable D
WHERE Id IN -- ID must have null in both From and to fields
(
    SELECT 
        D.Id 
    FROM 
        dbo.YourDataTable D 
    WHERE 
       D.[From] IS NULL AND D.[To] IS NULL
    GROUP BY 
        D.Id 
) 
AND Id NOT IN -- Except if the id has From or To in any of its rows
(
    SELECT 
        D.Id 
    FROM 
        dbo.YourDataTable D 
    WHERE 
       D.[From] IS NOT NULL OR D.[To] IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        D.Id 
) 
GROUP BY Id
```

You can add a calculated column named "noData" or similar to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourDataTable ADD hasData AS (IIF([From] IS NULL AND [To] IS NULL,0,1))
```

, add an index to it and use WHERE D.noData = 1 clause instead if you have many rows for better performance.

Comment: This query's result will include id 1 too

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion using except, all ids except those where from or to is not null

```
select id from t
except
select id from t where from is not null or to is not null
```